# Configuración de href en Json

Tags: html, json

Estoy montando una página web con Shopify, practicamente ya está terminada, solo me falta el footer.
[image: 1]

Así debería quedar, el footer, pero me queda así
[image: 2]

Esta es la parte del JSON:

```html
    "sections": {
      "footer": {
        "type": "footer",
        "blocks": {
          "8103412b-7d75-4ce6-9539-4490241d0a70": {
            "type": "contact_contact",
            "settings": {
              "widget_title": "Contactanos",
              "store_contact_info": "<li><span>MyShop Colombia <br> Tienda Online <br> Hecho en Colombia<\/span><\/li>\n<li> <span>+57 (301) 262-8565<\/span>\n<\/li>\n<li><span>ventas@myshopcolombia.com.co<\/span><\/li>"
            }
          },
          "1539233397020": {
            "type": "footer_menu_widget",
            "settings": {
              "widget_title": "Información",
              "link_url": "https://facebook.com",
              "link_title": "facebook"
            }
          },
          "3cc5f513-e153-4477-8420-d0e5da8195f8": {
            "type": "footer_menu_widget",
            "settings": {
              "widget_title": "Redes Sociales",
              "footer_menu_handle": "bof"
            }
          },
```

y este es el html:

```
       {
      "type": "footer_menu_widget",
      "name": "Footer Menu",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "widget_title",
          "label": "Widget Title"
        },
        {
          "type": "link_list",
          "id": "footer_menu_handle",
          "label": "Select Menu"
        }

      ]
   },
```

Agradezco su ayuda, quiero poner los enlaces de información como los de la primera foto gracias :)

Comment: Hola. ¿Y cuál es.tu pregunta, cuál es el problema o error?

Comment: Que quiero añadir los enlaces en ese apartao, he intentado de todas la formas posibles pero siguen sin aparecer en la página

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el código con el que intentas poner dichos enlaces?

Comment: Hola, @JesúsD.G.T. ¿Puedes probar reemplazando con `"link_url": "https:\/\/facebook.com"`? Añadiendo caracteres de escape.

Comment: @A.Cedano esta en la publicación, esos dos, un html y un json

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez lo acabo de probar, no funciono :(

Comment: Pero se supone que debes leer el JSON y construir un contenido HTML para mostrar en la página. ¿Dónde haces eso?